# prewritten code with JCodeModel

Tags: java, code-generation

So I'm in a situation where I need to generate code using JCodeModel, but a fair ammount of the code I need to generate would not need to be changed between the classes (I'd say only 10-20% needs to actually be generated at runtime)

How would I go about creating a class that is only partially generated? Or do I just have to convert the entire thing into the JCodeModel format because of how it compiles.

Also, if perhaps there is another code generation format that might be better suited for my needs i'd also be very interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Do you need to generate Java code or will bytecode suffice?  Also, is there a pattern to what you need to generate (ie: method interceptors)?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstract class (without even JCodeModel generator) and make all you code to inherit from it.

```
public abstract class Base {
    // all your common stuff
}
```

and in code model use:

```
<your generated class>._extends(Base.class)
```